# How to ping static IP of unplugged Ethernet device

Tags: networking

I'm running a virtual machine that has a static IP on the same subnet as my laptop. However when my laptop is unplugged from the Network even though my nic has a static IP I cannot connect to services running on my virtual machine as I would expect to. Additionally I can't even ping my nic because it appears the IP assignment requires it to be physically connected but I need to work abroad sometimes without physical connectivity. Do I need to physically created a loop back rj45 just to use ip services on a virtual machine. Any help is appreciated. Thx